# Identical strings not matching in Jest

Tags: javascript, string, jestjs

The following test fails:

```
test('', () => {
  const result = new Intl.NumberFormat('sv-SE', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'SEK',
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    maximumFractionDigits: 0,
  }).format(1000)

  expect(result).toEqual('1 000 kr')
})
```

It returns the following hint:

```
Expected: "1 000 kr"
Received: "1 000 kr"
```

I've tried assertion with `.toBe()` as well, giving the same result.

What is the correct way to assert the two strings above?

Comment: Try using `encodeURIComponent() ` and see what is different either log it or just to make it easy, alter the test `expect(encodeURIComponent(result)).toEqual(encodeURIComponent('1 000 kr'))`

Comment: I think that is a no-break space

Comment: I see. This is so confusing. Do you know the reason `Intl.NumberFormat` returns these characters, and any way to not have them? (Instead of using the `encodeURIComponent` in the assertion).

Comment: actually it makes sense for Intl to return no-br space so better not fighting that. No one will want to see "1000" and "$" on different lines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It returns a non breaking space in the output so you need to check for that too

```
expect(result).toEqual('1\xa0000\xa0kr')
```